# External Javascript to be loaded each time JSP get reloaded

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have an external JS file, that I have included in my JSP.
On first time loading of the Jsp the external JS file will also get load.

On second time if I reload the same JSP then JS is not reloading, If I clear the browser cookies then JS file is loading.
 I need external JS file to be load each time when JSP is refresh.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a param to the link which changes on every load - such as the current timestamp - should force bypass of the browser cache and trigger a reload on each request.

```
<script src="myscripts.js?randomParam=123456789"></script>
```